# Layering of eigenvalues

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\tau: V \to V$ is a linear transformation on a finite-dimensional real vector space with eigenvalues $a_1, \dotsc, a_n$, in ascending order,  and $P:V\to V$ is orthogonal projection onto $W \subset V$, with $\dim W = \dim V -1$, then if $\sigma: W \to W$, $ \sigma = P\tau|_{W}$, with eigenvalues $b_1, \dotsc, b_{n-1}$, then

$$a_1 \leq b_1 \leq a_2 \leq b_2 \leq \dotsb \leq b_{n-1} \leq a_n.$$

I believe there is a more general version of this fact. Can someone provide a reference?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the interlacing eigenvalue theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem Does that helps?

Comment: Yes, thanks!-------

Comment: I put this in answer form, so we don't clog up the site with unanswered posts.

Comment: Sounds good!-----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the Interlacing Eigenvalue Theorem (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem)). To find out more, you can consult Horn and Johnson.